# how to write this Query in Lighthouse-php? -> Blog::where('status', 1)->where('title', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')->paginate(6)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, graphql, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse

I fetch data using a query like this in my `Laravel` project :

```
-> Blog::where('status', 1)->where('title', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')->paginate(6);
```

Now I'm using `Laravel+Lighthouse-php` for my backend API.

how to write this Query in `Lighthouse-PHP`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eloquent Scopes in model to scope your status condition:

```
public function scopeEnabledBlogs($query) {
    return $query->where('status', 1);
}
```

and in your schema use:

```
extend type Query {
    Blogs(title: String @where(operator: "like")): [Blog!] @paginate(scopes: ["enabledBlogs"])
}
```

Now you can query your blogs like:

```
query {
    Blogs(first: 6 title: "%something%") {
        data {
            title
        }
    }
}
```